# import ExecutionContext.global and ExecutionContext.Implicits.global at the same time in scala

Tags: scala

I have following test case:

```
test("test future") {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    case class Result(value: String)
    val f = Future {
      println("Start future")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("End future")
      Result("The Job is finished")
    }

    f.onComplete({
      case Success(r) => println(r.value)
      case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
    })


    //Hold the test thread
    Thread.sleep(3000)

  }
```

There is compile error that complains `Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext`

But If I remove `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global` from the code,
then it works.

I would ask why it doesn't work if I import both `ExecutionContext.global` and `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

Comment: Just wondering, why would you import both? It's literally the same `ExecutionContext`...

Comment: I happen to hit this problem, When I write code and I remember to import ExecutionContext.global,but I first import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global  which is incorrect,then I try to import  the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.{ global => ImplicitsGlobal }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
```

Comment: Thanks! I really want to know why implicit doesn't work in my case(two global are imported)